# Is there a solution to sideload app from external device via USB and running it without install?

Tags: android, external, autorun, adk, dongle

I'm looking for the solution to develop an external device(Android-powered) for smart phone with Android embedded that can sideload app via USB and auto-run like PC2PC USB transfer cable without installing application. I want everyone could plug and play without further settings, installation, no doubt having no root and USB debugging mode turned on.

Is there a solution for doing such a thing like that?
I mean external device has Android app itself. And When it connect to phone via USB, the application will sideload app, put it to runtime for an auto-run and takes over touchscreen control to instruct the external device but still run no secure risk.